# Obtener elemento con mayor valor de un HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

Tengo un `Hashmap` el cual guarda la marca del carro y las veces que se repite en una cadena,

```
Map<String,Integer> sh = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

Si realizo un recorrido al `Hashmap` obtengo el siguiente resultado:

código :

```
for (Entry<String, Integer> o : sh.entrySet()) {
            System.err.println(o.getKey() + " - " + o.getValue());
        }
```

Resultado:

```
toyota - 1
nissan - 5
mazda - 3
```

Necesito obtener la marca que tenga el value mayor este caso "nissan"

```
nissan - 5
```

Es solo un ejemplo por en realidad el hashmap que tengo contiene por más de 1500 elementos.

Comment: crea una variable temporal que almacene el mayor `value` comparandolo cada iteracion del  `for` junto con el nombre de la marca. Cuando acabes el for solo tienes que mostrar esa variable con el nombre

Comment: ¿Puedes tener valores mayores iguales? En ese aso ¿Qué decisión tomas?

Comment: bien pensado @Héctor , quizá quiera todos en ese caso

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puesto que la pregunta básica es como ordenar un Map aquí te dejo una función para ordenar Maps extraída del siguiente [comentario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/sort-a-mapkey-value-by-values-java) del autor [Carter Page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/309596/carter-page)

```
import java.util.*;

public class MapUtil
{
    public static <K, V extends Comparable<? super V>> Map<K, V> 
        sortByValue( Map<K, V> map )
    {
        List<Map.Entry<K, V>> list =
            new LinkedList<Map.Entry<K, V>>( map.entrySet() );
        Collections.sort( list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<K, V>>()
        {
            public int compare( Map.Entry<K, V> o1, Map.Entry<K, V> o2 )
            {
                return (o1.getValue()).compareTo( o2.getValue() );
            }
        } );

        Map<K, V> result = new LinkedHashMap<K, V>();
        for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : list)
        {
            result.put( entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() );
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Y esta es la versión para Java 8 que ordena en orden ascendente, para el orden descendente solo hay que descomentar la línea `Collections.reverseOrder()`.

```
public static <K, V extends Comparable<? super V>> Map<K, V> sortByValue(Map<K, V> map) {
    return map.entrySet()
              .stream()
           .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(/*Collections.reverseOrder()*/))
              .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Map.Entry::getKey, 
                Map.Entry::getValue, 
                (e1, e2) -> e1, 
                LinkedHashMap::new
              ));
}
```

Una vez tengas ordenado el mapa de mayor a menor puedes obtener los valores mayores con un simple for que lo recorra y almacene en otro mapa resultado los elementos iguales al mayor valor hasta que aparezca el primer elemento de menor valor.

```
Map<String, Integer> finalResult = new HashMap<>();
int maxValue = -1;
for(Entry<String,Integer> entry: result.entrySet()){
    if(maxValue<0){
        maxValue = entry.getValue();
    }
    if(entry.getValue()>=maxValue){
        finalResult.put(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue());
    }else{
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Al menos me gustaría saber porqué alguien me puntúa negativamente

Comment: Tal vez porque es  una respuesta con metodos que copiaste de internet. Pero eso no debe ser causa para darme puntos negativos.

Comment: Por cierto Como demuestras que esto funciona para varios elementos maximos.????

Comment: Fe puesto la fuente, por tanto no es copia. He recopilado, no he copiado todo el contenido, por tanto tampoco es copia. He traducido el contenido. Por tanto no es copia. Es más, he añadido la solución al problema propuesto. Por tanto tampoco es copia. En cuanto al número máximo de registros. En cuando a la demostración. Simplemente ejecuta el último fragmento de código con un array ordenado de mayor a menor, que es lo que pone en la entrada que he escrito.

Comment: Otra cosa, no te he dado puntos negativos porque yo haya hecho mi post a partir de otro de internet. Que por cierto he mencionado como ya dije, lo he hecho porque no cumple con lo que se hablaba en el hilo.

Comment: **Como te  agregue en mi respuesta ya probaste esta información que copiaste?** te sugiero también agregues los creditos ya que es copia.:)

Comment: Si, claro que la probé. ¿La probaste tú? En cuanto a los créditos. Dejo claro en la publicación que la he extraído de otro lugar del cual dejo el enlace

Comment: Agrega los enlaces y los autores originales por favor.

Answer (score 0):

Otra solución sería así ;)

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class ElementoMayorHashMap {

public ElementoMayorHashMap() {
    Map<String, Integer> sh = new HashMap<String, Integer>() {
        {
            put("toyota", 1);
            put("nissan", 5);
            put("mazda", 1);
        }
    };

    imprimeMax(sh);// Out -> nissan - 5

    Map<String, Integer> max = getMax(sh);

    System.out.println(max);// Out -> {nissan=5}
}

private Map<String, Integer> getMax(Map<String, Integer> sh) {
    Map<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<>(Comparator.reverseOrder());

    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : sh.entrySet()) {
        map.put(entry.getValue(), entry.getKey());
    }
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        return new HashMap<>() {
            {
                put(entry.getValue(), entry.getKey());
            }
        };
    }
    // solo llega aquí si está nulo el map sh
    return null;
}

private void imprimeMax(Map<String, Integer> sh) {
    Map<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<>(Comparator.reverseOrder());

    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : sh.entrySet()) {
        map.put(entry.getValue(), entry.getKey());
    }
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(String.format("%s - %d", entry.getValue(), entry.getKey()));
        break;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ElementoMayorHashMap();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto es lo que yo llamo llegar tarde jajaja, pero bue, ya que alguien trajo esta pregunta, y las respuestas dadas me parecen demasiado costosas (por tener que ordenar) aparte de no contemplar la posibilidad de varios elementos...

```
Map<String, Integer> repeticionesMarcas = new HashMap<>() {
   {
      put( "toyota", 1 );
      put( "Nissan", 5 );
      put( "mazda", 1 );
      put( "Yukasa", 5 );
   }
};

Map<String, Integer> devuelveMayores( Map<String, Integer> data ) {

      // creamos el mapa a devolver
   Map<String, Integer> aux = new HashMap<>();
   int valor = 0;
   for( Entry<String, Integer> dato : data.entrySet() ) {
      int repe = dato.getValue();

         // si el dato es igual a valor, agregamos
      if( repe == valor ) {
         aux.put( dato.getKey(), repe );
      }

         // si el dato es mayor, reseteamos "aux", agregamos y actualizamos "valor"
      if( dato.getValue() > valor ) {
         aux = new HashMap<>();
         aux.put( dato.getKey(), repe );
         valor = repe;
      }
   }
   System.err.println( aux );
   return aux;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

### HashMap: ¿Como obtener obtener el elemento con el valor mayor?.

puedes hacer uso de este método, el cual compara el valor de cada entrada para obtener el valor máximo:

```
 public static Entry<String, Integer> getMaxEntry(Map<String, Integer> map){        
    Entry<String, Integer> maxEntry = null;
    Integer max = Collections.max(map.values());

    for(Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        Integer value = entry.getValue();
        if(null != value && max == value) {
            maxEntry = entry;
        }
    }
    return maxEntry;
}
```

como ejemplo suponiendo este `HashMap`:

```
HashMap map =  new HashMap<String, Integer>() {
{
        put("toyota", 1);
        put("nissan", 5);
        put("mazda", 3);
        put("bmw", 4);
        put("kia", 2);
        put("dacia", 0);
    }
};
```

El Entry con valor máximo sería

```
   ("nissan", 5)
```

el cual se puede obtener llamando el método de esta forma:

```
  Map.Entry<String, Integer> maxEntry =  getMaxEntry(map);
```

---

Con **Java 8** puedes obtenerlo de esta forma:

```
Object maxEntry = Collections.max(map.entrySet(), Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).getKey();      

System.out.println("maxEntry = " + maxEntry);
```

tendras el resultado :

```
nissan
```

---

### ¿Como ordenar valores en un HashMap?

Se puede realizar mediante este método:

```
public static <K, V extends Comparable<? super V>> Map<K, V> 
    sortByValue( Map<K, V> map ){
    List<Map.Entry<K, V>> list =
        new LinkedList<Map.Entry<K, V>>(map.entrySet());
    Collections.sort( list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<K, V>>(){
        public int compare(Map.Entry<K, V> o1, Map.Entry<K, V> o2){
            return (o1.getValue()).compareTo( o2.getValue() );
        }
    });

    Map<K, V> result = new LinkedHashMap<K, V>();
    for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : list){
        result.put( entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() );
    }
    return result;
}
```

el método anterior puede ser llamado de esta forma, obteniendo los valores ordenados, como ejemplo el siguiente `HashMap`:

```
HashMap map =  new HashMap<String, Integer>() {
{
            put("toyota", 1);
            put("nissan", 5);            
            put("mazda", 3);             
            put("bmw", 4);
            put("kia", 2);
            put("dacia", 0);            
    }
};
```

llamamos el método para obtener un Map con los valores ordenados:

```
 Map valoreOrdenados =  sortByValue(map);
```

puedes iterar para ver el resultado:

```
Iterator it = valoreOrdenados.entrySet().iterator();
   while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " => " + entry.getValue());
    it.remove(); // evita ConcurrentModificationException =)
}
```

teniendo como resultado

```
 dacia => 0
 toyota => 1
 kia => 2
 mazda => 3
 bmw => 4
 nissan => 5
```

Comment: Prueba los dos métodos y me comentas resultados.

Comment: A ver, hasta lo que veo en tu código el método devuelve un objeto Entry de un solo registro. Dime tú de donde sacas los n Entry que pueden tener valor máximo.

Comment: El OP no busca solo ordenar, eso es muy sencillo, busca **Necesito obtener la marca que tenga el value mayor este caso "nissan"**

Comment: Y también se dijo que fueran n elementos máximos. No uno solo. Ya comenté en mi entrada que la pregunta era ordenar y por eso puse un método de ordenar.

Comment: Estoy respondiendo en tu respuesta.